# Best practice: new DateTime() vs DateTime.Parse()

Tags: c#, datetime

Let's say I am creating an instance of a class object that has both a name and date. Which is considered best practice when setting the date?

```
var employees = new List<Employee>() 
{ 
    new Employee {Name = "Foo", HireDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 15)}, 
    new Employee {Name = "Bar", HireDate = new DateTime(2001, 5, 25)}, 
};
```

or

```
var employees = new List<Employee>() 
{ 
    new Employee {Name = "Foo", HireDate = DateTime.Parse("2000, 1, 15")}, 
    new Employee {Name = "Bar", HireDate = DateTime.Parse("2001, 5, 25")}, 
};
```

I am assuming there really isn't a huge difference, but I am slightly new to C# so I am not sure which is prefered by the majority of C# programmers and why (performance, readability, etc.). Thanks in advance for any insight you can give!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prefer `new DateTime`.

In favor of `new`, it will allow you to use variables directly:

```
// clean because the variable is applied directly to the function
int year = 2000;
var date1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 15);
var date1 = new DateTime(year, 7, 3);
var date1 = new DateTime(year, 8, 19);

// kind of gross and prone to errors because it is appended to the string
int day = 23;
var date1 = DateTime.Parse("2001, 5, " + day.ToString());
```

In argument against `Parse`, it doesn't detect errors until runtime:

```
var date1 = new DateTime(200fdsa, 1, 15); // Error on compile
var date2 = DateTime.Parse("2001fdsjf, 5, 25"); // Must run to find the error
```

`DateTime.Parse` will always have poorer performance, because it needs to run code that detect errors and converts the string to numeric values.  It does this while your program is running.

However - in cases where you *must* accept string input (e.g. from a text file), you should use the tool built for the job: `DateTime.Parse`.

---

If you're interested in simplifying the specification of date/time constants in your code, there is a library that Jon Skeet wrote for that.

It is a bit old and unmaintained, but the specific code (extension methods on integer constants/date and time structures) probably doesn't really need a lot of maintenance.

- [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/)

The source code for those extensions is under `MiscUtil\MiscUtil\Extensions\TimeRelated\` (inside the source zip)

It will let you write your date times in a friendlier fashion, yet still give you clean code with similar performance to `new DateTime(2012, 11, 13)`:

```
DateTime someDateAndTime = 19.June(1976) + 8.Hours();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the benifits and consequences. This is very insighful!

Comment: This answers everything I was assuming was the case but was unsure. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for pointing out that strings always suck compared to plain code.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose this is ultimately subjective, but I cannot conceive of any good reason for using `Parse` in this situation.  Why perform an (inefficient) string parse over a simple constructor that takes the actual component values?

Comment: I think that comes down to what data you have.. If you have the individual parts as ints, by all means use the no string method.  However, if you have the string version (think a datetime field in a web app) use the parse method.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just use `new DateTime()` in the example you provided. You know exactly what the year/month/day components of the date are. Why create a string and parse it?